# How can I send a list of array to parse and retrieve it and show it in a UItableView?

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays, uitableview, parse-platform

I am developing a chat app in iOS .There I need to add friends of the currentUser into an array and then send it to parse and save it there as an array.
As the user should add the their friend only one time and after that I need to do some functionalities there.
So How can I check that the user is already added as friend as well as how can I retrieve the array of friends?
Please if anyone can suggest me something then it will be a great help for me as I am new to iOS and Parse.

Comment: you use array of  user pointers .

Comment: @MuhammadAdnan sorry I can't understand what are you trying to suggest.Can you please elaborate?

Comment: if its a singleUser chat , you can get friend info from Friend's table. Otherwise you have to keep array of PFusers (participating in chat ) . 1 colum of array type in parse Chat table

Comment: @MuhammadAdnanyeah i have created a column named as Friends but I can't figure out how to filter the users which were already added

Comment: You are asking a lot of different questions in one question.  If you break it down, the answer are already here on SO.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a join table on Parse which stores who is friends with who.
With a `PFQuery` you can then filter it to get only the friends related to a certain person. You could call this table "Friendship", which stores 2 User objects, meaning, they are friends.

*Update*

You would have a PFObject subclass called `Friendship`. the `Friendship` object would hold 2 things, one is the `User` and the other is the `Friend`. Both should be `PFUser` type.

You don't need to go into parse for creating the join table, if you create a new object in code and save it, parse will create a table for it. So if you create the first `Friendship` object and save it, parse will keep it in it's own table of Friendships.

Saving a Friendship would be just like this:

```
- (void)addFriend:(PFUser *)friend {
    Friendship *friendship = [[Friendship alloc] init];
    friendship.user = self.user;
    friendship.friend = friend;
    [friendship saveInBackground];
}
```

This is just a simple example.

To fetch a list of friends from the user:

```
- (void)fetchFriendsList {
    //create a query for friendships
    PFQuery *friendsQuery = [[PFQuery alloc] initWithClassName:[Friendship parseClassName]];
    //filter it to find only friends for the user
    [friendsQuery whereKey@"user" equalTo:self.user];
    [friendsQuery findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *friendships, NSError *error) {
        if (!error) {
            //do something with the list of friendships
            self.friends = [friendships valueForKey:@"friend"];
            //the above line create an array with only the friend value of each Friendship object inside the array
        } else {
            NSLog(@"error fetching friends: %@", [error description]);
        }
    }];
}
```

To find out if the friend is already added/exists:

```
- (void)friendExists:(PFUser *)friend withCompletionBlock:(void (^)(BOOL))completionBlock {
    //create a query for friendships
    PFQuery *friendsQuery = [[PFQuery alloc] initWithClassName:[Friendship parseClassName]];
    //filter it to find only friends for the user
    [friendsQuery whereKey@"user" equalTo:self.user];
    [friendsQuery whereKey@"friend" equalTo:friend];
    [friendsQuery findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *friendships, NSError *error) {
        if (!error) {
            //if we get one result here, it means it already exists
            BOOL alreadyExists = friendship.count > 0;
            if (completionBlock) { //making sure there is a block as parameter
                completionBlock(alreadyExists);
            }
        } else {
            NSLog(@"error fetching friends: %@", [error description]);
        }
    }];
}
```

You need to have a block in there to treat the results, since making a PFQuery request is not instant.
Also , when adding more `whereKey:`, they are treated as "AND", which means, it will only return objects that comply with all the whereKeys.

That's basically it. I assume you know how to subclass the PFObject, if not, you can take a look at the [documentation](https://parse.com/docs/ios/api/Classes/PFObject.html).

Comment: can you please give me some link or give me some example regarding this.